# What is the best practice in case one argument is null?

Tags: c#, .net, argument-validation

when validating methods' input, I used to check if the argument is null, and if so I throw an ArgumentNullException. I do this for each and every argument in the list so I end up with code like this:

```
 public User CreateUser(string userName, string password, 
                            string Email, string emailAlerts, 
                            string channelDescription)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Username can't be null");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Email can't be null");
       //etc, etc, etc
    }
```

Is this OK? Why should I do this? Would it be ok if I simply group all the checks and return a null value instead of throwing the exception? What is the best practice to address this situation?


**PS:** I want to change this, because with long methods, it gets very tedious to do so. 
 Ideas?

Comment: The single parameter constructor for ArgumentNullException should take the name of the argument - a verbose comment is unncessary.

Comment: Awesome tip David M! Never took the time to read the overloads :) .. Thanks

Comment: As I'v ended up using Lou's answer, I will accept it. Thx everybody for your help! appreciate it!

Comment: In C# 6.0, you can use the `nameof` built-in to get the name of your argument: `if (foo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(foo));`. This pattern is useful in most of the answers below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make an ArgChecker class with something like this

```
  ArgChecker.ThrowOnStringNullOrEmpty(userName, "Username");
```

where ThrowOnStringNullOrEmpty is

```
  public static void ThrowOnStringNullOrEmpty(string arg, string name)
  {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name + " can't be null");
  }
```

You could also try to process a list of arguments using a params arg, like:

```
  public static void ThrowOnAnyStringNullOrEmpty(params string[] argAndNames)
  {
       for (int i = 0; i < argAndName.Length; i+=2) {
          ThrowOnStringNullOrEmpty(argAndNames[i], argAndNames[i+1]);
       }
  }
```

and call like this

```
  ArgChecker.ThrowOnAnyStringNullOrEmpty(userName, "Username", Email, "email");
```

Comment: I like it! Specially for the params thing. Thanks Lou +1

Comment: The only problem I have is that ArgumentNullException might not be appropriate for an empty String, since it isn't null. Perhaps some other form of invalid or illegal argument exception would be better.

Comment: @Thomas see my answer below :)

Comment: If you would use a simple tool as SonarLint, you would notice this is a bad practice. There is also a discussion on various places that you should not be checking for null, you should let the environment throw NullReferenceException

Answer (score 18):

An approach which I use and I may have picked up from the NHibernate source is to create a static class `Guard`, used as follows:

```
public void Foo(object arg1, string arg2, int arg3)
{
    Guard.ArgumentNotNull(arg1, "arg1");
    Guard.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(arg2, "arg2");
    Guard.ArgumentGreaterThan(arg3, "arg3", 0);
    //etc.
}

public static class Guard
{
    public static void ArgumentNotNull(object argument, string parameterName)
    {
        if (parameterName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parameterName");

        if (argument == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
    }
    //etc.
}
```

This cuts down a lot of the chaff at the beginning of methods and it performs well.

Comment: That looks better than mine indeed. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 9):

You should think about the method, what it needs to do and with what data. If null values represent actual failure conditions, use exceptions. If null values are acceptable, accept them.

Think about the principles from [design by contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract), specifically what the preconditions to your function are, and standardize a way to enforce them (which Matt and Lou both suggest in their answers so I don't need to go into detail).

Another important thing to consider is the size of your method signatures. If you have a lot of parameters for your methods, this probably means you have bad abstractions. You can cut down on the number of parameter checks you have to make if you group parameters together in collection objects and use those objects as parameters. You can move the parameter checking to those objects instead of having to check them in every function that uses them.

So instead of passing ten related parameters to every function, figure out the few that are used in every function and package them up in an object, and include in that object methods to validate the parameters. This has the added advantage of being easy to change should the rules regarding one parameter need to be updated.

Comment: Thanks Welbog. Yes the null are failure conditions. I think the size of my methods signature is pretty acceptable (7 args max). About grouping the args into an object, I think this will create an object with no identity, how should i represent this object in the domain model?

Comment: Well, seven arguments max is a good rule of thumb, but if a lot of related methods use the same set of arguments it's still a good idea to group them. You can model them however you want. If the common arguments are domain-oriented (i.e. employee data), name them after their domain counterpart (i.e. employee). If they are implementation-oriented (i.e. session-specific data), name them after what they represent to the application (i.e. session). If the arguments that are common are not related in any way other than being used in a lot of methods, leave them ungrouped.

Comment: In _Clean Code_, Robert Martin considers, not 7, but zero - that's right, zero - the ideal number of parameters, with one a close second.  Using Wellbog's good ideas here you should be able to get a lot closer to those ideals.  It's very interesting, sometimes very nice, when you try to push those limits; you'll be surprised how possible it is and how much better you like your code.

Answer (score 5):

And for the C# 3.0 developers amongst us a great way to encapsulate this null checking is inside an extension method.

```
public void Foo(string arg1, int? arg2)
{
  arg1.ThrowOnNull();
  arg2.ThrowOnNull();
}

public static class extensions
{
    public static void ThrowOnNull<T>(this T argument) where T : class
    {
        if(argument == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    } 
}
```

And if you wanted you could always overload that to take an argument name.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the method apparently being called on a null object, although I appreciate this is legal for an extension method. File under 'syntactic dissonance'.

Answer (score 3):

A small improvement to Lou's answer would be to use a hashtable instead, it means it checks objects aswell as just strings. Also just nicer to populate and handle in the method:

```
public static class ParameterChecker
{
    public static void CheckForNull(Hashtable parameters)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry param in parameters)
        {
            if (param.Value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Value as string))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(param.Key.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you would use like:

```
public User CreateUser(string userName, string password, string Email, string emailAlerts, string channelDescription)    
{
    var parameters = new Hashtable();
    parameters.Add("Username", userName);
    parameters.Add("Password", password);
    parameters.Add("EmailAlerts", emailAlerts);
    parameters.Add("ChannelDescription", channelDescription);
    ParameterChecker.CheckForNull(parameters);

    // etc etc
}
```

Comment: If you're going to wrap things into a hash table, you might as well create your own statically-typed structure or class to abstract this kind of thing away. With a class you have more control over what types the properties are and what it means for them to be valid.

Comment: It would be easy enough to just do another check against the param.Value i.e. if (param.Value is Type) and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would stick with your original approach, except for just passing in the parameter name. The reason is that once you start writing those helper procedures it becomes an issue when everyone starts using different conventions for how they write the helper procedures. When someone looks over your code, they now have to check to make sure you've written the helper procedure correctly when debugging your code.

Keep checking each argument separately, though youor fingers grow weary from typing Grasshopper :) Your followers will bless you when they get the unexpected ArgumentException and are saved from a debugging run just to determine which argument failed.

Comment: Man! I really care about my coworkers, I love'm, actually we're kissing up (just kidding) :). I don't think that calling such a tiny function to check for null or empty can confuse anyone though.

Comment: You'd be surprised how what is simpler and clearer to you may be less so to someone else. The worst code I ever read was by someone who felt that all the C constructs should be replaced with macros defining new looping constructs etc. :) I think he got halfway to C# before he was done (or maybe F#)

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-5.0) (which is meant to contain multiple exceptions) with a list of multiple [`ArgumentNullException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=net-5.0) instances. Don't forget to also take advantage of the `parameterName` argument of `ArgumentNullException` which works great with [`nameof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof):

```
var exceptions = new List<Exceptions>();

if (firstArgument == null)
    exceptions.Add(new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstArgument), "Some optional message"));

if (secondArgument == null)
    exceptions.Add(new ArgumentNullException(nameof(secondArgument), "Another optional message"));

if (exceptions.Count > 0)
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first advice to you is get ReSharper. It will tell you when there is a problem of possible null values, and when there is no need to check for them, and with the click of a mouse will add checking. Having said that...

You don't have to check for int or bool, which cannot be null.

Strings can be checked with string.IsNullOrEmpty()...

If you still decide that you want to check each and every parameter, you can either use the Command design pattern, and reflection, but your code will be unnecessarily clunky, or use the following and call it for each method: 
    private myType myMethod(string param1, int param2, byte[] param3)
    {
        CheckParameters("myMethod", {param1, param2, param3});
        // rest of code...

And in your utility class put this:

```
///<summary>Validates method parameters</summary>
///... rest of documentation
public void CheckParameters(string methodName, List<Object> parameterValues) 
{
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName) )
       throw new ArgumentException("Fire the programmer! Missing method name", "methodName"));

    Type t = typeof(MyClass);
    MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod(methodName);
    if ( method == null )
       throw new ArgumentException("Fire the programmer! Wrong method name", "methodName"));
    List<ParameterInfo> params = method.GetParameters();
    if ( params == null || params.Count != parameterValues.Count )
       throw new ArgumentException("Fire the programmer! Wrong list of parameters. Should have " + params.Count + " parameters", "parameterValues"));

    for (int i = 0; i < params.Count; i++ )
    {
            ParamInfo param = params[i];
            if ( param.Type != typeof(parameterValues[i]) )
                throw new ArgumentException("Fire the programmer! Wrong order of parameters. Error in param " + param.Name, "parameterValues"));
            if ( parameterValues[i] == null )
                throw new ArgumentException(param.Name + " cannot be null");
    }
} // enjoy
```

Comment: `int` cannot be `null`; it can be `0`. `int?` can be `null`.